# Make input text accept numeric percent only Angular

Tags: html, angular, regex, typescript

How to make text input only accept percent values? Is there a way to do that by deleting non numeric values and adding ' %' at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to make text input accept float numbers and add "%" at the end:

- **in html file:**

```html
<input id="id" type="text" formControlName="percentControl" (focusin)="start($event)"(focusout)="end($event)" />
```

- **in .ts file:**

```js
  end(e) { 
    // console.log(/^[0-9.]*$/.test(e.target.value));
    if(!/^[0-9.]*$/.test(e.target.value))
        e.target.value = e.target.value.replaceAll(/[^0-9.]/g, '').trim();
   //add ' %' at the end
    if(e.target.value.length)
        e.target.value = e.target.value+ ' %';
    //this part is needed when working with angular form validation (ngForm required 
    //or formGroup Validators.required), else null value won't trigger the validation
    else 
        e.target.value = '0 %';
  }
  start(e) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace('%', '').trim();
  }
```

- **dealing with data transfer to and from the back-end:**

1. Posting data:

```js
 //make sure to get rid from ' %' when posting data to the backend
 //example with formControl
 // the + is for converting string to number
 dataToPost = +this.form.get('percentControl').value.replaceAll('%', '');
```

2. Getting data:

```js
 //Use Angular percent pipe
 local: string = "en-US";
 percentPipe:PercentPipe = new PercentPipe(this.local);
 myVariable = this.percentPipe.transform(dataFromBackEnd/100);
```